# What is best way to resubmit a callable as soon as I get a result from the future?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there a better way to do this?  I would rather use an existing framework from j.u.c instead of rolling my own....

Please look at the "run" method.

I need to resubmit the Callable as soon as a result is obtained from the Future.
I'm using this separate Runnable Thread, just to do exactly this, as shown below.

Though this should compile, its obviously not a working piece of code..

```
public class ResubmitOnCompletion implements Runnable {

    private CompletionService<DeviceData> completionService;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Device> devices;

    public void run() {

      //-- keep resubmitting the callable.
      while(true){


        try {
          //-- Get the returned data from completed job
          Future<DeviceData> f=null;
          DeviceData dd=null;

          f = completionService.take();

          //-- Get the completed job's data 
          dd=f.get();

          //-- now resubmit the job if device still is part of the active device collection
          completionService.submit((Callable<DeviceData>) devices.get(dd.getDeviceId()));
      }
      catch (CancellationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }         
    }   
  }


    //-- Device Data
    private class DeviceData {
      /**
       * Unique Device Identifier
       */
      private final String deviceId;

      /**
       * Holds all numeric data of the device.
       * Key=Variable id of the parameter
       * Value=Numeric value of the parameter
       */
      private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal> numericData;



      private DeviceData(String deviceId,
          ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal> numericData) {
        super();
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.numericData = numericData;
      }


      /**
       * @return the deviceId
       */
      public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
      }

      /**
       * @return the numericData
       */
      public ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal> getNumericData() {
        return numericData;
      }
    }   

    //-- Device
    private class Device {
      public DeviceData call() throws Exception {
        return new DeviceData("",new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BigDecimal>());
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply submit the Runnable and within the run re submit itself

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

private void submitWork(){
   e.submit(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
          ///do work with devices and get its data            
          e.submit(this);
       }
   });
}
```

I am unsure why this would not work.

Comment: It should work.  
But instead of runnable, can I resubmit from Callable?  Sorry Not formatted..


    worker.submit(new Callable<Object>(){
                    public Object call(){
                      //-- Do work, get data, store it somewhere 
                      Object data=new Object();
                      storeit.put("id", data);

                      //-- resubmit work
                      worker.submit(this);

                      //-- return data (ignored)
                      return data;

                    }//-- call
                  }//-- callable
                  );

Comment: Where are you returning to?  That wouldn't work because you lose the Future and the value returned after the first invocation

Comment: as i noted in my answer with the same content, you need to be careful that your executor has an unbounded queue, otherwise you can deadlock your executor.

Comment: The fixedThreadPool uses an unbounded queue.  The only way at this point you can deadlock if its a single thread pool and you are trying to invoke get() on the returned future within its callable

Comment: @John V:I wont be using the returned Future with this implementation. Since call{} will do the actual job, by the end of the method, it'll have the result ready as "data". Then I store the data calling some ConcurrentMap (storeit.put). So by the time I reach the last line, my task is already done and I've already extracted and stored the data in "storeit" and finally I've resubmitted the task.  The last line of return is just to complete the call method contract and return a Future, but I dont need it.  Wont that work? @jtahlborn Thanks for pointing out the deadlock.

Comment: @Amit Ok I see.  If that's the case you don't necessarily need a Callable.  You could do what you linked in your comment and it should work fine.  However from a readability point of view it would probably confuse people as to why you are using a Callable with no need for its returned Future.  That is why I suggested Runnable

Comment: @John V:Ok. Sorry I didnt mention that I'll be storing the future as well in another concurrentMap (storeFuture.put).  Storing the future will allow me to cancel the task if needed. So Callable-Future will give me that benefit. so when I resubmit from within the "call" I'll capture the future and storeFuture.put it.  I wont be doing a future.get() anywhere...just future.cancel if required.

Comment: Ok so as long as you do something like `Future<?> f = e.submit(this); concurrentMap.put(f,f);` Then you should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make the job itself check the status at the end and resubmit itself if necessary.  this will work as long as your executor has an unbounded queue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an ExecutorService/CompletionService is what you want really. If you want the job to continue, then you are really have a worker thread that is producing a `BlockingQueue` of results.

If you need to restrict the number of threads running at any particular time that is a different concern, but for the moment you can simply store a `ConcurrentMap<String, BlockingQueue<DeviceData>>` that the producer thread uses to put results into and the consumers reads results from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I actually do need to limit the number of threads.  My tasks are > than number of threads, so to make it scalable, I need to use completionService with Executor. Can the solution you provided become scalable ? If it can, then I could change my approach.